# Difference between Delphi and Delphi.NET

Tags: .net, delphi

I am kinda new in programming and I was wondering what is the main difference between Delphi and Delphi.NET? I hope I can get some examples about their differences, be it syntax or structures.

By the way, is there any "simple and easy" compiler for Delphi.NET ? (such as Dev for C++ which is kinda simple)

Comment: Delphi.NET is a now defunct product that is no longer developed. You should simply forget about it. There was only ever one compiler, the one sold by Embarcadero.

Comment: With Embarcadero Prism it is possible to make .NET programming using a  Delphi like language. Never used it though, and never will.

Comment: There is a "SharpDevelop" based version of Prism which is pretty easy to use, but the regular Embarcadero Prism (which supercedes delphi.net) comes inside the Visual Studio shell (light version of visual studio) which is also pretty easy. What did you want to do exactly?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Embarcadero is still selling Delphi for .Net? there is someone who is buying it in our days?!?

Comment: @rba I do not believe it is being sold today

Comment: @RBA, no. The key word in David's original comment is **was** - Delphi for .NET died with Delphi 8, even though VCL for .NET survived a couple of versions afterward. Delphi Prism is the current Delphi for .NET development.

Comment: Thanks for all of the reply. It was really helpful. I was asked to learn this language so I have no choice. Anyway I downloaded Borland Delphi 8 for .NET Framework to develop a Delphi .NET project. I was wondering is there any syntax between delphi and delphi.net? For instance, is both using WriteLn to output message?

Comment: Delphi 8 for dotnet is deprecated. But RemObjects have products for those that want to mix Delphi and dotnet. See http://www.remobjects.com.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) is the language and IDE to create native Windows, Mac and iOS applications.

Delphi.NET is a deprecated version to generate .NET applications. The current alternative to create .NET applications using a Object Pascal syntax is use [Embarcadero Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/prism).

Comment: Delphi Prism when bought from Embarcadero is really a relabelled version of "Oxygene by RemObjects" which in the future could even go back to being just "Oyxgene" or "Prism" by RemObjects.  Given that the uptake and usage of Prism is very very low in the overall delphi community, I'd expect it to silently disappear from the RAD Studio product within the next five years, going the way of Blackfish SQL, ECO, and a dozen other dead-now things.

Comment: Ugh, "deprecated", "defunct"... *discontinued* is that word! Granted, Delphi.NET has never reached acceptable quality state.

Comment: Oxygene Pascal (RemObjects) is very much alive. It's a part of their Elements language package, where you can use C#, Oxygene and Swift. You can also compile to native and webassembly. So its evolved on the side, decoupled from Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is quite simple: Delphi was designed originally to create applications which run on Windows OS without any other 'interpreter'. That means that you were developing an application in Delphi and Delphi will generate the machine code needed.

When .NET arrived the guys from Borland create a separate compiler which was a layer on this  technology, so the Delphi developers continue to create applications which work on that, without being forced to learn a new language and a the new platform(more or less).

From my knowledge the only tools which are more or less 'Delphi' developer friendly are Delphi for .Net(from old Borland) and the Prism compiler(known also as Oxygene) from RemObjects.

Comment: A couple of "nitpicks". .NET is not an "interpreted" language (which your answer implies), and Delphi for .NET was not a "layer on top" of Delphi. It was a separate compiler which produced true IL which, combined with the Borland.Delphi assemblies, produced true *compiled* .NET applications. (They're compiled and become true executable code the first time they're run on the target system; interpreted apps are never actually compiled, but are simply interpreted and executed at runtime.) Not downvoting, but your answer isn't accurate. :)